# Did Severus Snape have a Dark Mark?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

I have seen all the movies and read all the books and quite familiar with the fact that all Death Eaters have Dark Mark on their forearm. Severus Snape was a prominent Death Eater and Voldemort's one of the most trusted one. But I never got an impression that he had a Dark Mark too neither in the books or the movies.

I remember that in *The Goblet of Fire*, when Voldemort was restored to his body, he called all the Death Eaters except for Snape. I thought this could be because of his lack of a Dark Mark.

Yet I don't know for sure if Snape really lacked a Dark Mark on his forearm. If he indeed had no Dark Mark, what could be the reason?

Comment: Don't forget that Snape was undercover, couldn't openly display any loyalty to V.

Comment: So even if he had, we would not know easily?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is downvoted. It's a decent question and OP not remembering every detail in the book is not a reason to downvote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

He shows it to Fudge in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*.

> Snape strode forwards, past Dumbledore, pulling up the left sleeve of his robes as he went. He stuck out his forearm, and showed it to Fudge, who recoiled.
>
> ‘There,’ said Snape harshly. ‘There. The Dark Mark. It is not as clear as it was, an hour or so ago, when it burnt black, but you can still see it. Every Death Eater had the sign burnt into him by the Dark Lord.

Comment: And furthermore, he clearly *was* summoned -- but he refused the summons.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Did he let Fudge know that he was summoned? That would be terrible I suppose.

Comment: @Proscionexium Whether Fudge picked up on it or not, he did -- because that's what made the Dark Mark burn black...